# Analytic function $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {z^{2n-1}}{2n-1}.$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, analytic-functions

Let $f:\{z:\|z\|<1\}\rightarrow \{z:-\frac{\pi}4<\operatorname{Im}(z)<\frac {\pi}4\}$ such that $f (z)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{z^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$. How to prove that $f(z)$ is analytic and also injetive. I have been able to show that $f$ is analytical due to the analytic convergence theorem:

If $(f_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ sequence of analytic functions defined in a region $A\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ and $f(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(z)$ uniformly converges in any closed disk in $A$, then $f(z)$ is analytic in $A.$

But I have not been able to demonstrate that $f(z)$ is injective, could you give me any idea about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to MSE.

Meaning the principal branch of log, we can sum the series (it's sometimes known as the inverse hyperbolic tangent):
$$
2f(z)=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2n+1}}{2n+1} = \log(1+z)-\log(1-z)=\log\left( \frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)
$$If $f(z)=f(w)$, then
$$
\log\left( \frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)=\log\left( \frac{1+w}{1-w}\right)
$$Exponentiating, we see that
$$
-1 - \frac{2}{1-z}=-1 - \frac{2}{1-w},
$$or $z=w$.